# Adding Mimetypes to MimetypesFileTypeMap

Tags: java, mime-types

I'm having trouble adding Mimetypes to MimetypesFileTypeMap. I've tried adding a META-INF/mime.types file just like the [Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/jaf/javadoc/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) says to. but it doesn't seem like it is getting read by MimetypesFileTypeMap.

Am I missing something?

It is a Spring/Maven Web project. Any help would be appreciated!

---

Even stranger side point.  A passerby (Andrew T.) was doing some investigation into MIME types just the other day & uncovered this documentation in the `MimetypesFileTypeMap` JavaDocs.

---

### MIME types file search order:

The `MimetypesFileTypeMap` looks in various places in the user's system for MIME types file entries. When requests are made to search for MIME types in the `MimetypesFileTypeMap`, it searches MIME types files in the following order:

1. Programmatically added entries to the `MimetypesFileTypeMap` instance.
2. The file `.mime.types` in the user's home directory.
3. The file `<java.home>/lib/mime.types`.
4. The file or resources named `META-INF/mime.types`.
5. The file or resource named `META-INF/mimetypes.default` (usually found only in the `activation.jar` file). **(A)**

**(A) As demonstrated by the [code posted by jwrobel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308142/adding-mimetypes-to-mimetypesfiletypemap/6333057#6333057), the Jar actually seems to be the `resources.jar` on at least two systems (with JDKs).**

---

So given this source..

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;

class TestMime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

        File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "lib");
        f = new File(f, "mime.types");
        System.out.println(f.exists() + " \t - " +f);

        f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".mime.types");
        System.out.println(f.exists() + " \t - " +f);

        MimetypesFileTypeMap mfm = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
        System.out.println(mfm.getContentType("a.js"));
        System.out.println(mfm.getContentType("a.png"));
        System.out.println(mfm.getContentType("a.jpg"));
        System.out.println(mfm.getContentType("a.au"));
        System.out.println(mfm.getContentType("a.htm"));
    }
}
```

..we can rule out '1' - programmatically added.  We can also forget 4 & 5 if we run it from the command line in a directory with no `META-INF`, no `activation.jar` on the class-path.  Which only leaves options 2 & 3.

Yet the output of this source is..

```
1.6.0
false    - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\mime.types
false    - C:\Users\Andrew\.mime.types
application/octet-stream
application/octet-stream
image/jpeg
audio/basic
text/html
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I.E.  The `false` result on both files that could be the source of the MIME mappings shown for the file strings, suggest those last two source of info. don't exist.  So where the heck is the information coming from?

Comment: N.B. Everything after "Even stranger side point.." added by me, because I think it is strongly related to the OP's question.

Comment: After looking into the [source for MimetpesFileTypeMap](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.java.htm) it looks like MimetypesFileTypeMap relies on ClassLoader.getSystemResource to load the files. So, the problem might have something to do with the resource not being in the classpath. Unfortunately, I don't have anymore time today to look into this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165873/why-does-mimetypesfiletypemap-always-return-application-octet-stream-for-png-f/46265038#46265038

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring provides [a wrapper class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.html) which comes packed with a more updated MIME type list. You use it pretty much the same way you'd use MimetypesFileTypeMap.

```
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap;
...
ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap mimeMap = new ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap();
String contentType = mimeMap.getContentType(uploadedName);//defaults to application/octet-stream
```

Comment: For X.png files it returns image/x-png , but it need to  return image/png. I think it is not correct nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

To answer Andrew Thompson, I think that MimetypesFileTypeMap is getting its default MIME Type definitions from /lib/resources.jar:/META-INF/mimetypes.default.

**Running this code from the command line:**

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); 
URL resource = loader.getResource("META-INF/mimetypes.default"); 
System.out.println(resource.getPath());
```

**Yields**:

```
file:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_22/jre/lib/resources.jar!/META-INF/mimetypes.default
```

[MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.java.html)  uses ClassLoader.getResource() to load the default mimetypes.

Comment: Good call.  The results are much the same here (same Jar).

Comment: opps, I forgot to post my environment:
    java version "1.6.0_22"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: Note, if you are using Java 7, then this file is missing.  See bug https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7096063

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mimetype to MimetypesFileTypeMap in your Javacode

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
mimeType.addMimeTypes("application/pdf pdf");
```

The key info here is addMimeTypes argument must be 
"mime_type extension" eg: "application/pdf pdf" as shown above.