# Estimate if file is MIME type

Tags: java, mime-types

This method should be check if a file is MIME type. To achieve this goal I am using method [probeContentType()](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29).
However maybe is another way to decide same question. Which are the other alternatives (if there are any)?

**Code:**

```
class ProbeContentTypeCheker implements Checker {

    @Override
    public boolean check(File fileCheck) {
        try {
            Path filePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
                    fileCheck.getAbsolutePath());
            if ((Files.probeContentType(filePath) != null)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

- Are there other alternatives to check MIME type in files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 approaches for getting a file mime type:

1. Identifying by the file's [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) - this is a reliable approach but it requires reading information from the file
2. Guessing it by the file extension - this is a fast approach, but can be less accurate

The following solution use the 1st approach:

1. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) - a toolkit for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries
2. [JMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) - a Java library for determining the MIME type of files or streams
3. [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) - enable Java programs to detect MIME types based on file extensions, magic data and content sniffing

The following solution use the 2nd approach:

1. javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap - this part of the JavaBeans Activation Framework. The MimetypesFileTypeMap looks in various places in the user's system for MIME types file entries.
2. Using java.net.URL - mapping between the extension and the mime-type is defined in the file [jre_home]/lib/content-types.properties

For some more information see this [post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html)

Comment: Can you add another variants checking MIME types (enumerate list)?

Comment: Do you mind me asking, if you can see at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325047/check-file-of-mime-type-with-jmimemagic).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `mime-util`, it works great even on a 9GB+ file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(theFile);`.

Note that if no MIME type is found, `application/octet-stream` is returned instead of `null`.

Comment: `getContentType(theFile)` => Can we check there `theFile.getAbsolutePath()`? And after fixed - is this valid [`check(File fileCheck)`](http://pastebin.com/SpmFGZGf)?

Comment: public boolean check(File fileCheck) { String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileCheck);  if (mimeType == null) { return false; }    return true;  } - Is this correct?

Comment: @nazar_art No, since as I said, if no MIME type is found, `application/octet-stream` is returned instead of `null`. `application/octet-stream` is usually the default MIME type of any file, if no other more specific has been found.

Comment: If this [MimetypesFileTypeMap()](http://pastebin.com/bcpyEgrw) isn't correct? How we can repair this method and to prove good work file check method?

Comment: Copy the source of class MimetypesFileTypeMap and set static variable 'defaultType' null. But I would not do that unless there is a specific reason. It is possible that you may need additional mime types added, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308142/adding-mimetypes-to-mimetypesfiletypemap

Comment: @Adi What is better variant at this situations?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to Use `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(String fileName)` if you cannot use Java 7.
Note that if the content type cannot be guessed, the method will return `null`.