# Java returns YAML mime type null

Tags: java, yaml, mime-types

Java 8 `Files.probeContentType(new File("config.yml").toPath());` returns `null`.
Why java couldn't find yaml mime type, but can find xml as `text/xml`? Is there any other way?

```
foo: bar
```

Comment: Because YAML probably is not out of the box supported. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155087/estimate-if-file-is-mime-type?r=SearchResults&s=3|38.7817

Comment: My OS is Microsoft Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

[The default implementation on Windows](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/1e8cdf311133/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/RegistryFileTypeDetector.java) uses the registry to find the content type. You would need to create the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.yml` and add a string value underneath it called `Content Type` that has the value that you want to use as the MIME type. You can save the following as `yaml.reg` and use it to add the necessary keys for you:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.yml]
"Content Type"="application/x-yaml"
```

Alternatively, if you want to use [`Files.probeContentType(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) but do not want to rely upon the provided default implementation, you can create your own [`FileTypeDetector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html):

```
package com.example;

public class CustomFileTypeDetector extends FileTypeDetector
{
    public CustomFileTypeDetector()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public String probeContentType(Path path)
        throws IOException
    {
        // Some error checking omitted for brevity
        String filename = path.getFileName().toString();

        if (filename.endsWith(".yml") || filename.endsWith(".yaml")) {
            // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/332159/21926
            return "application/x-yaml";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You will also need to create a file that [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) can find because that is how it discovers implementations of `FileTypeDetector`. Assuming maven, you would create a file:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector
```

With the following content (based on the example code above):

```
com.example.CustomFileTypeDetector
```