# In Java 6, how do I properly get mimetype for files that are videos?

Tags: java, video, mime-types

I'm using Java 6.  I'm trying to write a boolean method to tell me if a filename is that of a video.  I have tried this ...

```
final String fileName = "video.mp4";
String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(new File(fileName));
```

but the value of mimeType is "application/octet-stream" when I expect it to be "video/mp4".  What is the best way to determine if a particular file (which may not exist on my system) is a video?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Do you have to use java 6? That could have some security concerns...

Comment: This discussion might be useful (especially if you are using Spring): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308142/adding-mimetypes-to-mimetypesfiletypemap.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have to use Java 6.  Regarding the other thread posted, I'm using Spring, but I'm not clear on how the answer that was awarded the bounty applies to me.  Can you post the code or instructions I would use as an answer here?